# Question about JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript

What kind of JavaScript is this `Page.getProximityListCallback = function(obj) {`; is this a function?

Surely it is but what is it with this syntax? Can someone explain?

**Update**:
Thank you for your answers. Here is a follow up: Why then use `function Page() {}`? What is its purpose? Why not just call getProximityListCallback()?

Answer (score 2):

It's an anonymous function which is then assigned to a variable.

http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 1):

You can have namespaces in your JavaScript code using objects like this:

```
var Page = {};
Page.getProximityListCallback = function (obj) {
    // ...
};
```

And remember that

```
function func(obj) {
    // ...
}
```

is the same thing as

```
var func = function (obj) {
    // ...
};
```

So in your example you are assigning an anonymous function to the Page object's getProximityListCallback member.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are "first class" values in JavaScript, that is, you can have a constant of type "function" and assign it to a variable or object member, just like you do with numbers or strings. Compare

```
    var foo = "cow";
```

and

```
    var bar = function() { }
```

Conceptually there is no difference between these two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can think of like adding a method to the Page class. In run-time.
Method then will be accessible via the `Page.getProximityListCallback()` call.

Check here (JavaScript tab) - http://jsbin.com/arocu/edit.

BTW: it's a nice service to have fun with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

possibly Page can have other related methods